# How to call @canExecute method from a class

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I'm working on eclipse rcp4 application and I'm facing a problem with @canExecute annotation method . When I send
        broker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID);
 it will trigger all canExecute method but I want to restrict to a certain classes only .
Could any one help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to the `UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC` event call can be something that implements `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.Selector`.

So, for example, to just update a specific element id you could use:

```java
Selector selector = element -> "element id".equals(element.getElementId());

eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, selector);
```

If you just want to update a single element you can just specify the element id as the second parameter:

```java
eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, "element id");
```

Comment: greg, where are those things documented, ie what kind of object/data can be passed to the `eventBroker.send()`method? thx

Comment: @titou10 Documentation is poor, I only recall seeing this in one of the developer's blogs, it is also covered in the JavaDoc for UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC. What you can specify depends on the event topic

Comment: @Greg , Thanks for answer , I tried with that but no luck. below is the description of the question .We are developing pure Eclipse Rcp-4 Application with multiple parts and no. of tool bar contributions items .
During opening of any Part all the tool bar items are registered and If multiple parts are opened , all parts of tool bars items are registered and 
if I try to switch the tab , all parts of canExecute annotation methods are called but we need only active part canExecute methods should be called.  Thanks ,

Comment: This answer is only for when you do a UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC in your code and definitely works with the correct selector. You can't control what the core e4 code does when it wants to check enablements.

Comment: Also note that the core e4 code checks enablement a lot on all sorts of events.